# Convert binary file to text file

Tags: text, binary

I'm struggling with a srt subtitles, which are a binary file for some reason:

```
file -i file.srt
file.srt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

When opening them in kate (KDE text editor) they look fine. I can even cat them - also everything is printed out as expected, according to srt format.

In vim it is obvious, that file is in binary form (unreadable characters).

Unfortunately, they do not work on TV.

How can I convert them to plain text?

Comment: Unless you give the file there's nothing people can help you with.

Comment: Can you include the output of `hexdump -C < file.srt | head`?

Comment: It could be encoded in something like UTF-16LE, in which case `iconv -f UTF-16LE < file.srt > new-file.srt` or even `dos2unix --assume-utf16le < file.srt > new-file.srt` to fix the other MS crap if any  may help.

Comment: If it look fine in kate, why no just ask kate what type of file it is? `Tools->Encoding` and see what's checked.

Comment: All files are binary. What do you mean by binary? It is clear that you mean non-text.But also, you suggest that it is a text file. Edit the question, to make it clear what the problem is. Tell us what happens where (use pictures if you have to). Tell us what you expect.